# Warning: flatten is not a function Use --force to continue

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gruntjs

I have very strange error with grunt. For some reason after some time in our CI system, this task start to fail. May be someone faced with same issue?

When I run **grunt assemble:site** it outputs:

```
Running "assemble:site" (assemble) task
Warning: flatten is not a function Use --force to continue.
```

How possible to fix this error? Some configuration problems in the task?

Gruntfile.js assemble task part

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({

        //other tasks
        assemble: {
            options: {
                production: true,
                ext: '.html',
                data: 'src/data/*.json',
                assets: 'dist/assets',
                helpers: 'src/helpers/*-helper.js',
                layoutdir: 'src/templates/layouts',
                partials: ['src/templates/partials/*.hbs']
            },
            site: {
                options: {
                    layout: 'default.hbs'
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'src/templates/pages',
                    src: ['*.hbs'],
                    dest: 'dist/'
                }]
            }
        },

        //other tasks

    });

    //other loadNpmTasks

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-assemble');

    //other registerTask

    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'concat:bootstrap',
        'concat:js',
        'uglify:js',
        'copy:js',
        'assemble',
        'prettify',
        'sprite',
        'svgmin',
        'sass',
        'postcss',
        'copy:gfx',
        'pngmin'
    ]);
}
```

Package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "html-prototype",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "HTML prototype",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.7.2",
    "grunt": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-assemble": "^0.6.3",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "^3.0.4",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-newer": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-pngmin": "^1.0.2",
    "grunt-postcss": "^0.8.0",
    "grunt-prettify": "0.4.0",
    "grunt-sass": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-string-replace": "^1.3.1",
    "grunt-svg-sprite": "1.4.0",
    "grunt-svgmin": "^4.0.0",
    "node-sass": "~4.5.0",
    "postcss-placehold": "^1.2.0",
    "postcss-svg": "^1.0.6",
    "svg-sprite": "1.4.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "digits": "~0.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "grunt-build": "grunt build"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here was some problem with the package itself. [More info here](https://github.com/assemble/grunt-assemble/issues/68).